# Not able to add ng-controller to ion-view-model

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I have a signup template/view written using ionic framework but whenever I submit the Signup form the value of ng-model `$scope.account` remains *Undefined*. According to me the main reason for this is that I am not able add controller name (SingupController) in signup.html. Whenever I add ng-controller="SingupController" and run the app browser get closed with a message **"Unable to attache. Operation is timeout"**

*I am using Visual Studio 2013, AngularJS, Ionic and Adobe PhoneGap.*

Here is a is the code which I am using.

**singup.html:**

```
<ion-header-bar>
    <button class="button" ng-click="closeSignup()">Cancel</button>
    <h1 class="title">Sign up</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content ng-controller="SignupController">
    <form ng-submit="doSignup()">
        <div class="list list-inset">

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="account.firstName">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="account.lastName">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="account.email">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="School" ng-model="account.school">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Country" ng-model="account.country">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="account.password">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="account.confirmPassword">
            </label>
            <p>Minimum 8 characters a-Z, 0-9</p>
        </div>

        <label class="item">
            <input type="submit" class="button button-block button-balanced" value="Sign up" />
        </label>
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

**And my controller code in controller.js is as follows:**

```
angular.module('angularApp.controllers', [])

.controller('SignupController', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout', '$http', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http) {
    // Form data for the login modal

    $scope.account = {};

    // Create the signup modal that we will use later
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/signup.html', {
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    // Triggered in the signup modal to close it
    $scope.closeSignup = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    // Open the signup modal
    $scope.signup = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.doSignup = function () {


        var config = {
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:60923/api/account/",
            data: $scope.account
        };
        $http(config).success(function (data) {
            $scope.mydate = data;
        });

    };
}])
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/app-overrides.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="scripts/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="angularApp">

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
</html>
```

I am really not sure where the problem is? Please advice me if you see any problem inside my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Have you added the path of controllers.js to index.html
2) Have you added the 'angularApp.controllers' as dependancy to your app.js module

Comment: I have no issues adding the controller in Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/J0WxxgcHxsLlsNTgTM0Y?p=preview (had to remove the ionic parts since I dont have the files> probably @Sabarish got a point ;-)

Comment: @Sabarish, yes both points you mentioned are done.

Comment: ok, try initialising by adding $scope.account = {} before // $scope.signupData = {};

Comment: I have added the $scope.account = {} but browser (Chrome) is not responding. I want to know that in @ABr demo, ion-content section has been injected directly to the main view, which is index.html I guess, but in my project index.html is being treated as master page and I have separate html templates like signup, signin which got merged at run time. Please see the updated code section so for more information. So I want to know this makes any difference? Or it just another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Did you have injected 'ionic' in your module? I miss it in your module definition.

Comment: Yes, this has been handled inside app.js file.  Which contains this line ''angular.module('angularApp', ['ionic', 'angularApp.controllers'])"

Comment: Have you included ng-cordova.min.js file above cordova.js in your index.html file, and I have executed your code by including that file it is working perfectly for me

Comment: @Anilkumar, I have added the ng-cordova.min.js as you said, please have a look at the updated index.html file. I have also injected the "ngCordova" module like this "angular.module('angularApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'angularApp.controllers'])" but unfortunately it is still not working on my side. Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller simply add `$scope.account = { }` to the initialization code. The issue is almost certainly that the `account` is being dynamically defined on a child scope. I can't prove that because I don't see the resulting HTML in the post, but I've seen this many times before.

Comment: I have already did that and still it is not helping me. When I run my app browser remains in processing mode and never loads the view.

Comment: If it's not loading the view then this problem isn't likely related to that. It may be related to your controller though. Is it possible this request is failing: `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/signup.html'`? Looking at the network tab you'd see. Are you using `$templateCache`? If so then is it in `$templateCache`?